# Error while loading splash to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a splashscreen and after that loads I want a fragment to open. i did write my code but am getting an error.

**Below is my code.**

```
public class Splashscreen extends FragmentActivity {


// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);



    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE",MODE_PRIVATE)

                    .getBoolean("isfirstrun", true);

            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity

            if(isFirstRun) {

                LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                **fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body,fragment).commit();**


                getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isfirstrun", false).commit();

            }

            else {

                Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, Test.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }


            // close this activity
            finish();
        }



    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);



}
```

}

fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body,fragment).commit();

In this line (R.id.container_body,*fragment*) : "fragment" is underline in red.

Can someone guide me why am getting an error there?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this.**

**Change this part**

```
LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
```

**To this.**

```
Fragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
```

Define with Fragment while replace.

**Edit :**

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment Same for both.

```
    Fragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
```

And also same for Login Fragment.

Comment: @Ishita Have you import fragment instance in your class ? Any exception is their then pls post it.

Comment: I did extend my splash Activity to Fragment activity.Error am getting while running my app is "Error:(52, 84) error: incompatible types: android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be converted to android.app.Fragment" @jaydroider

Comment: @Ishita Make sure 1 thing in your fragment activity class which import you have android.app.Fragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment ?

Comment: I have imported android.support.v4.app.Fragment for all my Fragment @jaydroider

Comment: @Ishita so may be the problem is your Login Fragment contains import that is android.app.Fragment . Make sure your Login fragment also contains import same as in your fragment activity.

Comment: @Ishita If u still don't get my point then pls check my edited answer.

Comment: ok thanks it works.. fragment is no more underline in red. However my app still crashed after splashscreen. the error is :

No view found for :id /container_body) for fragment HomeFragment @jaydroider

Comment: @Ishita what container body id contains? I think it's might be your frame layout to replace fragment data.

Comment: @Ishita Try android.R.id.content instead of R.id.container_body. Might be solve your problem.

Comment: for my Login Fragment I have a relative layout of id: "relativelogin", I am not using frame layout.  so in my codes I am using relative login as shown below: 

LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativelogin,fragment).commit();

is it good?

Comment: @Ishita Just give a Try android.R.id.content instead of R.id.relativelogin. Might be solve your problem.

Comment: @Ishita Not only R.id.content . . .  Add this android.R.id.content . android before R.id.content. Try and check.

Comment: @Ishita Please accept the answer click right sign check mark at left. Glad to help you :) Thanks.